# Octopack only creating one of two artifacts in TeamCity using Octopus deploy

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, teamcity, nuget, octopus-deploy

I have a multiple project solution and am using Octopus Deploy and TeamCity for deployment.

I have installed the Octopack NuGet package on two projects that I wish to be created as artifacts during the CI build.

I have set the follwing in my build step:

[image]
and have checked the csproj files of both projects and can see:

```
 <Import Project="..\packages\OctoPack.2.0.26\targets\OctoPack.targets" />
```

However, after the build runs one of the projects has been packaged as an artifact and the other one hasn't and cant see what the difference between the two is.

Is there something else I should be doing in TeamCity or in my solution?

Comment: Could you attach a full build log from TeamCity? I'd like to check whether OctoPack is being run on both projects.

Comment: @PaulStovell I've added an answer below as it is now working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set the following in configuration manager on the project that wasn't producing the artifact:

```
Integration|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Integration|Any CPU
Integration|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Integration|Any CPU
```

Teamcity then happily produced the package.

Comment: Where exactly in the configuration manager for the project did you put this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check in the \packages\OctoPack.2.0.26\targets\OctoPack.targets file to your source control.