# TeamCity - no artifacts generated with Octopus Deploy / Octopack

Tags: msbuild, nuget, teamcity, octopus-deploy, octopack

I have a Visual Studio project, that's set up in TeamCity with a build-task to create artifacts via OctoPack (*3.0.43*). Next, a deploy-task, that receives the output NuGet-package from the build-task task (on successful build) as a dependency.

I've tried setting up the build-task using both the `MsBuild` build-runner and the `Visual Studio (sln)` one, but in both cases **no artifacts are created**.

I've added the OctoPack NuGet package to my Visual Studio project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found this one out myself:

When I added OctoPack NuGet package, all seemed well. Hinted by [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958074/octopack-only-creating-one-of-two-artifacts-in-teamcity-using-octopus-deploy) [posts](https://andersnordby.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/teamcity-octopack-octopack-not-running/), I looked to the `OctoPack.targets` file. Here I stumbled upon the `Install.ps1` file, that seemed to be supposed to inject some build-actions in the VS project's *.csproj* file upon adding the NuGet package to project.

Next up, I removed the NuGet package and tried re-installing, but this time using the *Package Management Console* (`View > Other Windows > Package Management Console`) with command:

```
Install-Package OctoPack
```

This output the following:

> Successfully added 'OctoPack 3.0.43' to MySolution.MyProject. & :
>   File
>   C:\somepath\mysolution\packages\OctoPack.3.0.43\tools\Install.ps1
>   cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
>   For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:3

So, some security stuff was preventing the PowerShell script to do its stuff with the *.csproj* file.

**Solution:**

In the same window (*Package Management Console*) or in an elevated PowerShell, execute

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Retry NuGet package-installation (still same window or using the NuGet GUI) - now the NuGet package installer should inject whatever your version of OctoPack wants it to. After this, my TeamCity build started generating OctoPack artifacts correctly.